# Can we just roll up the identification tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm not a big fan of having the seperate tags, [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) and [identify-this-tv-show](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-tv-show).  I think these are cumbersome and we should just have an identification tag.

For further support, there are only 21 questions on the tv tag.

Answer (score 2):

## ***Strongly Disagree***

---

The purpose of the two tags is to separate our two forms of media that we have on this site.

- Movies
- Television

The act of separating them lets the potential reader know, with the [identify-this-tv-show](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-tv-show) tag *"I saw this TV show, and IDKWTFBBQ it is? PONIES?!"*

Whereas with the [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) tag, allows the reader to know that the question is  about a *movie*, narrowing the scope, even by just a little bit.

---

Lumping them together only further widens the scope of the question, therefore making it even harder for people to answer the question.

Comment: Ooo, fight fight fight..... :-)

Comment: FWIW - on this one I agree with TylerShads

Comment: I honestly believe that all information to narrow the search **should be in the question**.  If a user says "I saw this sci-fi movie" or "sci-fi tv show" then the tag is mostly useless except for the identification part.  Also, what happens if they're not sure what media it was in?  Should we tag it with both?  I personally don't think so.

Comment: @DForck42 with that being such an edge case, i doubt itll have an impact.  And if they can't even remember how they viewed it or whether it felt likea TV show or a movie, then the question is probably terrible anyway.  One last point; what would we call it [identify-this-....PONY?]

Comment: I like scifi's story-dentification tag.  They also have a character-identification tag.

Comment: Strongly agree with your disagreement

Comment: @DForck42 *story-identification* can apply to *anything* that tells a story.  *character identification* sounds **bloody awful**  *Help me find this character that whines a lot then wins in the end*  <- 50% (statistic pulled from thin air) of *any* written work.

Comment: @tylershads I didn't really look at their character identification tag.  I was just trying to lay out how it's set up on Scifi.  As a larger site they don't see the need to have identification tags broken up into different mediums.